# i have four string values from method. how to combine strings?

Tags: java, string, input

so i will get the value of these string from a method, and i need combine them as a file address, but i can't combine the string like i did on FILE_PATH_STRING. I tried to use concat method, but it doesn't work too. FILE_PATH_STRING will always equal to the first string ,which is     WORLD_PATH  in this case

```
public static final String WORLD_PATH = "The World/";
public static String CONTINENTS_NAME="";
public static String COUNTRY_NAME="";
public static String FILE_TYPE="";

public static String FILE_PATH_STRING = WORLD_PATH + CONTINENTS_NAME + COUNTRY_NAME + FILE_TYPE;
public static File FILE_PATH = new File(FILE_PATH_STRING);
```

it should work like, when i click on a map, method will return the name of region to me,and i wills store them in those static string. I tried debug. All of the strings have a value and they correct. but FILE_PATH_STRING only equal to the first string i put in there. 
after i run the program, 
CONTINENTS_NAME = Asia
COUNTRY_NAME should equal to CONTINENTS_NAME  because that's how i set up my file address
FILE_PATH = .png this is method for load map

Comment: Are you sure it's not because the other strings are empty?

Comment: Can you post the code where you try concat, etc?

Comment: Welcome to SO.Give a sample output, how the output should be. so that SO community will be able to help you :).

Comment: Hi @BobbyAlexander, Kindly have a look at tag before asking such kind of questions

Comment: @anto I believe the tag wasn't present at the time.

Comment: Hi @ Bobby, I am sorry for my comment, @WayneUroda thanks for notifying this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am curious, how do you "have four string values from a method" - can you enlighten us on that? Because if it is anything like this:

```
getStrings(WORLD_PATH, CONTINENTS_NAME, COUNTRY_NAME, FILE_TYPE);
```

Then that's the problem - the function `getStrings()` can't modify those strings passed in.

I am only making wild guesses of course, since you haven't given enough information.

Can you do something like:

```
String path = getWorldPath() + getContinent() + getCountry() + getFileType();
```

That is, implement four separate methods to get the four separate parts of the path?

Otherwise you will have to define a type which can return all four strings at the same time, or return them in a container like an array:

```
void test()
{
    String[] pathParts = getStrings();
    FILE_PATH_STRING = pathParts[0] + pathParts[1] + pathParts[2] + pathParts[3];
}

String[] getStrings()
{
    String[] ret = new String[4];
    ret[0] = "The world";
    ret[1] = "South America";
    ret[2] = "Chile";
    ret[3] = ".txt";
    return ret;
}
```

Of course, if all you are going to do is concatenate the strings, you could do that in the `getStrings()` function.

Comment: hmmmmm then i will need 4 get method and 4 set method, it sounds complete

Comment: my method does not return string. i stored those values in those static variable when i get it, the method is void

Comment: PLEASE post the code? Also, you should try really hard to avoid using static variables. There only very few cases where you really should *need* a static variable.